# win32com error when use pyinstaller inside virtual_env

Tags: linux, python-2.7, twisted, pyinstaller, win32com

Error occurs when i compile in virtual_env . If compile without virtual_env ,it works. Packages are installed in the same and virtual_env in the general environment.If compile programm "hello world", all works. But if add the package 'twisted' it presented error.

pyinstaller - 3.2
Python 2.7.12 
setuptools 30.2.0
Platform: Linux-4.4.0-53-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial

The project itself requires packages

import json,ctypes,logging.handlers,os,sqlite3,pyudev,
subprocess,sys,threading,time,datetime,multiprocessing

from twisted.internet import reactor, task
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks, returnValue
from autobahn.twisted.wamp import ApplicationSession, ApplicationRunner
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, WebSocketServerFactory
from autobahn.wamp.exception import ApplicationError
from websocket_server import WebsocketServer

> 17428 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
>   17817 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.dom.domreg.py"...
>   17817 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
>   18077 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 2, in 
>   ImportError: No module named win32com
>   18198 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 2, in 
>   ImportError: No module named win32com
>   18317 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 2, in 
>   ImportError: No module named win32com
>   18451 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 2, in 
>   ImportError: No module named win32com
>   18885 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-nacl.py"...
>   18914 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-cryptography.py"...
>   18973 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sqlite3.py"...

When start the program:

> ImportError: No module named zope.interface
>   Failed to execute script pyi_rth_twisted

But this module I installed separately in the environment and the general. I try to play with different versions pyinstaller,setuptools,zope.interface. As a result, still rests against this error

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a blank `__init__.py` file where your `zope` package is located. To find where `zope` is installed, you can run:

```
help('zope')
```

the file path should be at the bottom. If this answer doesn't make sense try searching something like `zope pyinstaller`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but nothing helped. The search for solutions continues